# Salesforce package.xml

Tags: apex, xml

I am creating a XML file. How can we add related lists, tabs, sub-tabs in a XML file? Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you please provide more content?

Comment: i am creating a new xml file what i have created components in my org then how to set related list,tabs,subtabs in xml file/.

Comment: Is your real question that you're not sure how this would be represented in XML (not salesforce specific), or if you're not sure how to do this on the force.com platform ?

Comment: I assume you are talking about packege.xml which is used in migration tool. Am i right? Related lists are defined in Layout type, tabs are defined in CustomTab type. Here you have complete reference to the supported types: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm